# How to parse a part a file in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

I have a file called file.txt and it has this structure:

```
owner_name    : first_last_name
filesize      : 1000
is_legal_file : yes
date          : someDate

.
.
.
```

I want to get the value in fileSize. (1000 in this example.)

How do I get this information?

Comment: Hint: Use `ifstream` and `read`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file line by line until the second line, then [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) the second line by `:` and you'll have two strings: `filesize` and `1000`, then you could use [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/).

Comment: is it possible just to read the second line? ( because it's actially the 15th line.. and i want to save time instead of reading the file line by line)

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: It's not possible.  You have to read the file to find the line separators.  If it was at a known offset, you could seek to the position, but that doesn't seem like your case.  Anyway, worrying about going through 15 lines in a file definitely qualifies as premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way aside from strtok is to do a `while (infile >> myString)`.  Just figure out the number of the value you want and take it out.

```
std::string myString;
ifstream infile("yourFile.txt");
while (infile >> myString)
{
    //Do an if-statement to only select the value you want.
    //Leaving this for you since I think it's homework
}
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to do this by using char* instead of string?

Answer (score 0):

#### [Split (partition) a line using `sstream`](http://ideone.com/YCLYN)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  for (string line; getline(cin, line); ) {
     istringstream ss(line);
     string name;
     ss >> name; // assume spaces between all elements in the line
     if (name == "filesize") {
        string sep;
        int filesize = -1;
        ss >> sep >> filesize;
        if (sep == ":" && ss) {
          cout << filesize << endl;
          break;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
1000
```

Related: [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/4279)

Comment: thanks. is there a way to do this by using char* instead of string?

Comment: @user1106106: if you use `char*` then [`strtok_r()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html) is more appropriate.